# Get windows to acknowledge malwarebytes as a valid AV

Tags: windows-8.1, anti-virus

I am using malwarebytes, and as such have disabled Windows Defender's real-time protection (I have malwarebytes pro).

However, now windows is complaining that I don't have an AV installed and that my system is at risk. Is there a way to get Windows to see I have malwarebytes?

Comment: Is malwarebytes set to run always or is it set to run only when you tell it?

Comment: @Xavierjazz Run always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action Center relies on the program (the AV) to "register" itself, it does not take any active steps to find out if a program that is running is an AV and is up to date. If malwarebytes does not engage Action Center's API, nothing you can do will make Windows think it's an AV. To get rid of the warnings, change Action Center's settings to not monitor AVs.

Comment: I disabled them but now ITBrain (From teamviewer) keeps insisting that windows isn't fully protected.

Comment: Most likely it is not running, I suspect. I would contact support at MWBytes and check with them.